# Chamisha Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred fifteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer (ch. 48)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21858&pgnum=258), the total amount of time that the Jews spent in Egypt was 215 years: the 210 we're familiar with (from when Yaakov and his family arrived), plus five years from when Menashe and Ephraim were born. (It goes on to say that counting nights and days separately yields 430 years, the figure given in Exodus 12:40.)

Josephus (Ant. 2:15:2) also gives 215 years, but calculates it from Yaakov's descent to Egypt.